# linking symbol to class actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

There is a simple method of linking a symbol to a class in flash cs5 in the gui designer. But how can i do the same thing in actionscript alone using code because iam not using flash cs5. Iam using notepad++ and flex compiler.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you're asking.  If you're only using the Flex compiler and Notepad++ where are the symbols coming from?

Comment: in flash a symbol can be a image right. How can i embed a image as a object in actionscript code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this link will answer your question: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html

The essence is this:

```
[Embed(source="logo.gif")]
[Bindable]
public var imgCls:Class;
```

and what this does is tell the compiler to add `logo.gif` as a symbol whose class name will be `imgCls`.

To then use this in your code, you just have to create an instance of it and work as normal:

```
var myImg:BitmapAsset = new imgClass() as BitmapAsset;
addChild(myImg);
```

Comment: how can i display it on the sprite ?

Comment: i added keyboard listner and inside that i have code to move it but it doesnt move. My code is    myImg.x =++x  when user presses up button

Comment: @user44444444 - You probably want something like `myImg.x++`, but this is getting off-topic. Please would you open a new question concerning your movement issues, and mark this as accepted if it answered your original question. Thanks :)

Comment: hey i have one small question. The bitmap looks too large. The bitmap on file is way smaller than the one getting displayed. Is there a way of getting the original onto the sprite ?

Comment: oh ok i figured that out. you can use the myImg.ScaleX and ScaleY property. :) Thanks shanethehat.

Comment: The shouldn't be any scaling applied to the Bitmap, although for the sake of completeness I've updated my anser to make the object a `BitmapAsset`, not a `Bitmap`.  You should check if the container sprite is scaled by setting it's `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties to 1, or check the dimensions of your BitmapAsset by attaching it to an image control as shown in the link in my answer.