# How to add an FXG image to an AS3 FlashDevelop project?

Tags: actionscript-3, fxg

I've got an ActionScript 3 project in FlashDevelop. How can I embed an FXG file and use it? I've tried to import the file directly (`import graphics.Filename`) and instantiating it, but doesn't draw anything.

Comment: have you read this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805508/linking-symbol-to-class-actionscript

Comment: Sorry, it does work, I just got the instantiation wrong due to other code. How do I close this?

Comment: apparently I must register to delete or flag (or downvote)...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Adobe's plan for FXG was for use with the Flex Framework. You can see an example of [how to use FXG with Flex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WSda78ed3a750d6b8f26c150d412357de3591-8000.html).

If you embed the FXG in a pure AS3 project you pretty much have an XML an no built-in way to display it. You will need to use a 3rd party library to parse the XML and draw the data, which luckily the [FXGParser](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/seven/fxgparser/en) library handles for you.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928755/how-to-import-fxg-to-a-shape).