# How to import FXG to a Shape?

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, shapes, fxg

I can import FXG files as Sprites as follows:

```
import graphics.mypic; // graphics/mypic.fxg
var mysprite:Sprite = new mypic();
```

I don't always need the fancy things that come with Sprites. How can I import them to Shapes?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't cast them as Shape(s) - the internal compile-time FGX is built on top of Sprite. You can find that out by running

```
var tig:* = new tiger();
if (tig instanceof Sprite)
...
```

What George Profenza is referring to is runtime loading of FXG's

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a better way to do this know, but [last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170824/moving-symbol-around-drawing-objects/3272598#3272598) I've played with a nice [FXGParser](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/seven/fxgparser/en) library that simplified things a lot.

1. Get the library:

   svn export http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/FxgParser/
2. Use it:

   import fxgparser.FxgDisplay;
   import graphics.mypic;

   var fxg:XML = new XML(mypic);//this bit depends on how you load/embed the fxg xml
   var mysprite: FxgDisplay= new FxgDisplay( fxg );
   addChild( mysprite );

Goodluck!

Comment: Is this really necessary? For importing  it as a Sprite, the two lines in my question are enough.